# My graphics card

Tags: 16.04, amd-graphics, fglrx, gpu, gpu-driver

I’m trying to switch to Linux on my laptop.

I downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 and installed it, and expirience no problems, except for with my graphics card, an AMD Radeon hd 7610m.

I know that AMD no longer support the fglrx on newer Linux, and that I have to depend on open source drivers. The problem is that the screen shows many artifacts when there is more than one window on screen, especially when there's a lot of transparency or moving characters on screen.

Games works smoothly, however.

This problem was also present in Windows. In Windows, changing the ATI Graphics Powerplay settings to "Maximize battery life" reduced the problem dramatically. Also disabling the GPU, and only enabling it for gaming or video worked.

I can't do any of this in Ubuntu.
So what I’m asking if you can help me how to do at least one of these in Ubuntu

1. disable the gpu
2. manage the power settings of the gpu

   - Also I can’t find any option of changing this in my bios
   - I tried to enable low graphics mode in unity de and it helped (no crashes now) but the artifacts still shows up.

**Update**

- seems like I can’t get my intel graphics work to use switcheroo
- if work on battery (no charger) everything runs smoothly without any artifacts at all

Comment: your graphic card.

Answer (score 2):

As you ask in (1) for disabling the GPU I assume you have a hybrid configuration and want to disable your discrete GPU. You can use `switcheroo` for that.

### Activating Switcheroo

First check whether switcheroo is active, in a terminal type:

```
sudo grep -i switcheroo /boot/config-*
```

Your output should look like:

```
/boot/config-4.1.0-1-amd64:CONFIG_VGA_SWITCHEROO=y
```

Then you need to edit your config file of grub by doing:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

In the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=
```

add radeon.modeset=1 and delete nomodeset if there.
 So this line should look like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.modeset=1"
```

Finally update your Grub settings:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot your laptop.

### Turn off your discrete GPU

First you need to be root, in a terminal, type:

```
sudo su
```

Then, to display your GPU state type:

```
sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

Your output should look like
    0:IGD: :Off:0000:00:02.0
    1:DIS:+:DynPwr:0000:01:00.0

The GPU in use is marked with the "+". IGD states for Integrated and DIS for Discrete. If you're not on a Hybrid GPU config, you will have only one line.

To activate the integrated GPU:

```
echo IGD > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

To turn off the **not** used GPU:

```
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

You can recheck the state of your GPU by entering again:

```
sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

Note: X server does not manage switching graphic cards during use, so after your changes you will need to restart it:

```
service lightdm start
```

Or simply reboot your laptop.

Paraphrased from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics

Comment: Then I can’t switch while use and I have to restart every time?!

Comment: I don't know your exact configuration (hybrid intel hd graphics + Radeon ?) but if this is the case, it depends what you want to do: if you want your system to switch the GPU completely, you will have to restart lightdm (it's not a reboot of the computer but only of the window manager). I have hybrid config and I managed to get my Radeon HD 7500 to show in the additionnal drivers. Since then I have the option when I right-click a package in the Dash to "Launch with discrete GPU"

Comment: Yes I have hybrid intel+Radeon

Comment: The restart of lightdm seemed so easy after I tried it I didn’t know it’s different from restart it all works fine now thanks

Comment: Glad to help! You can mark it as answer if it solved you problem

Comment: Do I have to turn off the igd  every time i turn on the dis?!!

Comment: Not necessarily, try without turning it off, if it runs smoothly then let it on. If you get problems or laptop heating really much then yes. Usually the DIS GPU makes my fan going crazy anyway so, you decide :)

Comment: When I tried switcheroo I got error

Comment: Lw: cannot access no such file or directory

Comment: With which specific command? Did you enter `sudo su` before?

Comment: Yes I entered it

Comment: With sudo cat /sys/..../switch

Comment: Can you give me the output of `lspci | grep VGA`?

Comment: VGA  compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices,inc. [AMD/ATI] whistler le [radeon hd 6610m/7610m]

Comment: I seems you have only one GPU, which you told me is not true. Go to your software settings, in the tab Additionnal drivers and make sure to use the Intel one as well

Comment: I installed the intel gpu driver provided by 01.org and I’m sure of this but it doesn’t appear in additional drivers the only thing in that tab is :”using processor microcode firmware for intel cpus from intel microcode proprietary “

Comment: And this is exactly it : ) put it in use and apply changes, then when you do `lspci | grep VGA` you should see it (maybe after a while or a reboot) it then means that you're IGD GPU is recognized and able to be used. Then process with switcheroo making sure it's enabled as described, modify grub config file and that's it you can switch

Comment: It is in use already and I rebooted but when I do lspci | Greg VGA nothing appears except the amd one